# What happens to Crash Reports sent to Google?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, crashes

Many Android applications have bugs. These include app crashing, screen flickers or failing to start altogether.

The app crashes present the well-known `Unfortunately, **AppName** has stopped` screen. 
[image: Crash dialog]

But sometimes actually pressing the left button and sending the report seems like a bit of a waste of time since I never get to know what happened to the report.

**What does actually happen once this report is sent? Is it known what Google does with it?** Does Google pass them on to the developers of the app that crashed? And do we how many crash reports Google receives per day?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think Google won't diagnose those crashes for individual Apps, instead they only collect those reports and present to the developers responsible for the App, and it's their business to trouble shoot the problems. Please check the official document as below.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6083203?hl=en